# view collection of images in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development, and I am trying to find the view that is a single frame, that has a left arrow and a right arrow, that lets you cycle through a collection of pictures. Also, if I have a collection of bitmap objects, can I use that to initialize this viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Gallery view. It allows you to swipe left and right to go to the next element. You can also trigger the transition programmatically.

See this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Alternatively you could use the ViewPager from the compatibility package to create an even better swipe experience.